# Link .lib File on Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I working on a school project where I am utilizing a .lib file supplied by the instructor. I also have the accompanying .h file and `#include` it in the .cpp I am working on. When I compile I am getting :

`undefined reference to Image::Image(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'`

*Updated

My question is how to link a visual studio library (.lib) file when compiling on Linux. After searching I have unsuccessfully tried:

`#pragma comment (lib,"Image.lib")`

and

`#pragma include "Image.lib"`

Most other answers I have found point to regular VS project functionality which of course isn't available in Code. Thanks.

Comment: Any pragma like `#pragma comment (lib,"Image.lib")` would depend on your compiler not your IDE.

Comment: I am using g++ to compile

Comment: I do not believe g++ supports this. A `pragma ` is a compiler specific directive and if a compiler does not recognize a given `pragma` it is allowed to silently ignore it. You will have to specify the library on the command line. Note that if you have  a Visual Studio library it will not work with g++.

Comment: I remember him mentioning that it was indeed a VS library

Comment: Edited the question now that I think I have a better understanding of what I need to accomplish

Comment: A Visual Studio library is not going to work on Linux. Have you access to the source code so you can recompile and build a library that will work on Linux?

Comment: I wasn't able to procure the source code so I'm just going to pull my Windows box out of the closet and use it for now. Thanks for the guidance. At least I learned some new stuff for all the frustration.

Comment: Actually, googling around shows that .lib files are usually an archive with either dlls or coff-format object files, and gcc seems to support coff format. It would be useful if you could put the .lib somewhere, and link it here — I'll take a look if there's anything you can do.